# Page transitions for plain html sites?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, css-animations

I am currently working on an internal website for my office. I have been using vue.js for it's ability to easily maintain numerous pages of looping and dynamic content. I also selected vue because my research on it made page transitions seem pretty straightforward.

Regretfully, my IT department is reluctant to actually host the site on a server; forcing me to keep this project as a static folder of HTML pages. Because of this, vue page elements do not seem to work in an environment like this (<template>, <router-view>, etc.).

Is there a method of applying vue page transitions in a static html site? If not, is it possible to delay a page loading so I can include triggered css animations between pages?

Comment: I have also extensively researched the possible solution of adding a delay before loading the next page. Like plain html vue page transitions, I did not find a solution that suited my specific problem.

Comment: May not be exatcly what you're looking for, but perhaps loading the entire page content via AJAX, and swapping it out on a click?

Comment: @circusdei I don't have much experience with AJAX, but if the content can be dynamically loaded that way, it is a possibility. However, this internal site will house a LOT of content, and worry how that will impact performance.

But I will do some research on it for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no, you can use even  [Vue Cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to make any vue aplication and to be deployed on any type of web server, You only need a local computer to make all the bunble things (transpilation, minify js, preprocessCSS, etc) and when you need to deploy the app, the only thing to do its run the production comands on your local development computer (like "npm run prod") and upload only the reday-production processed files.

Vue works in two ways, Runtime + Compiler or Runtime only:

> Because of this, vue page elements do not seem to work in an environment like this (, , etc.).

The file components in Vue must to be 'compiled' with a Vue Loader compiler and for this to be acomplished you need to use some module builder like webpack.
[Is explained here in the oficcial documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)

But that does not mean that you need to use a module builder to make a site with Vue usign the custom components. If you do not want to use Webpack you can load in your page the Runtime + Compiler version of Vue and the compiler will "compile" all the non DOM tags to a Vue component, check the snippet

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    article: 'first'
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<section id="app">
    <header>
    </header>
    <transition appear name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <article key="first" v-if="article === 'first'" @click="article = 'second'">
        <h1>Title of the Page</h1>
        <p> some content (click me to change the content)..<p>
      </article>
      <article v-else @click="article = 'first'" key="second">
        <h1>Another Title</h1>
        <p> some content ..<p>
      </article>
    </transition>
</section>
```

Comment: I've used the Vue Cli in conjunction with local servers in the past (MAMP, Kalabox, etc). I'll need to research the topic independently, but if I could find a way to make a site hosted by the aforementioned platforms and still make it accessible to members of my team, then I this would work.

For the time being, it's simply a normal folder located on a company shared drive that offers no "real" hosting.

Comment: @JMC_3030 I dont quite undertand what you mean by "still make it accessible to members of my team", the deployment of the site its totaly independent of what tecnologies you use to develop the site. I wrote a snippet that I think is what you need.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had an opportunity to try this out using yarn and it was able to facilitate a way for me to build/test a vue.js application and was much easier than setting it up on a local host like i had previously done, thank you!

Comment: To elaborate on what I mean by accessible is could someone, for example, go into the dropbox desktop app to locate the folder I have containing this internal site, and open the index.html without the need for yarn or something similar to render? This internal site is meant for non-developers who I wager would prefer not to dip into a terminal just to view the site

Perhaps this was answered already in your previous comments, but I am still in the learning process and apologize for any confusion or ambiguous information on my part